# How to call mapStateToProps on each instance of a Component in React-Redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have a component called AuditionItem, multiple instances of which are added to the parent component called AuditionsList.

I have done export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AuditionItem)

From my experience mapStateToProps is called only for one instance of AuditionItem (the one that initiates the state change). But I want the mapStateToProps to be called for EACH instance of AuditionItem.

Is there a way to do this?

Here's my code for AuditionItem.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Moment from 'moment';
import colors from './../styles/colors';
import { store } from './../App';
import { addBookmark, removeBookmark } from './../actions/creators';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class AuditionItem extends React.Component {

  _toggleBookmark = (auditionId, bookmarked) => {
    if(bookmarked)
      store.dispatch(removeBookmark(auditionId));
    else
      store.dispatch(addBookmark(auditionId));
  }

  render() {
    Moment.locale('en');

    let bookmarked = (this.props.auditions.indexOf(this.props.auditionId) > -1) ? true : false;

    let roleString = String(this.props.role);
    if(roleString.length > 35)
      roleString = roleString.substring(0, 35) + " ...";
    let projectString = String("Project: (" + this.props.productionType + ") " + this.props.project);
    if(projectString.length > 35)
      projectString = projectString.substring(0, 35) + " ...";
    let productionHouseString = String("Production House: " + this.props.productionHouse);
    if(productionHouseString.length > 35)
      productionHouseString = productionHouseString.substring(0, 35) + " ...";
    let iconName = `ios-bookmark${bookmarked ? '' : '-outline'}`;

    return (
      <View style={styles.auditionItemWithBookmark}>
        <View style={styles.bookmark}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._toggleBookmark(this.props.auditionId, bookmarked)} >
            <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
        <View style={styles.auditionItem}>
          <Text style={styles.role}>{roleString}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.project}>{projectString}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.productionHouse}>{productionHouseString}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.auditionDate}>Begins: {Moment(String(this.props.auditionDate).replace('"','').replace('"', '')).format('LLLL')}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  auditionItemWithBookmark: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: colors.auditionItemBackgroundColor,
    borderRadius: 10,
    margin: 10,
    padding: 15,
  },
  bookmark: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 5,
  },
  auditionItem: {
    flex: 8,
    flexDirection: "column",
    backgroundColor: colors.auditionItemBackgroundColor,
  },
  role: { color: colors.auditionItemColor, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "bold" },
  project: { color: colors.auditionItemColor },
  productionHouse: { color: colors.auditionItemColor },
  auditionDate: { color: colors.auditionItemColor },
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    auditons: state.bookmarks.auditions,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AuditionItem);
```

And the code for the parent AuditionsList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import AuditionItem from './AuditionItem';
import Auditions from './../data/Auditions';
import { store } from './../App';

class AuditionsList extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { isLoading: true, data: []  }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this._refreshData();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if((this.props.location !== prevProps.location) || (this.props.roleType !== prevProps.roleType))
        this._refreshData();
    }

    _onRefresh() {
      this.setState({ isLoading: true }, this._refreshData() );
    }

    _refreshData = () => {
        Auditions.fetchAuditions(this.props.productionType, this.props.location, this.props.roleType).then(auditions => {
          this.setState({ isLoading: false, data: this._addKeysToAuditions(auditions) });
        });
    }

    _addKeysToAuditions = auditions => {
      return auditions.map(audition => {
          return Object.assign(audition, { key: audition.Role});
      });
    }

    _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
      return (
        <AuditionItem
          auditionId={item.objectId}
          role={item.Role}
          project={item.Project.Name}
          productionType={item.Project.ProductionType.Type}
          auditionDate={JSON.stringify(item.Date.iso)}
          productionHouse={item.Project.ProductionHouse.Name}
          auditions={store.getState().bookmarks.auditions}
        />
      );
    }

    render() {
      if (this.state.isLoading) {
        return (
          <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
            <ActivityIndicator />
          </View>
        );
      }

      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <FlatList onRefresh={() => this._onRefresh()} refreshing={this.state.isLoading} data={this.state.data} renderItem={this._renderItem} />
       </View>
      );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    location: state.settings.location,
    roleType: state.settings.roleType,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AuditionsList);
```

Code for App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Header } from 'react-native-elements';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';
import { SettingsDividerShort, SettingsCategoryHeader, SettingsPicker} from 'react-native-settings-components';
import BookmarksScreen from './screens/BookmarksScreen';
import AuditionsScreen from './screens/AuditionsScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen';

import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/lib/integration/react';
import { autoMergeLevel2 } from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';

const persistConfig = {
 key: 'root',
 storage: AsyncStorage,
 stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
 whitelist: ['settings', 'bookmarks']
};

const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = createStore(pReducer);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);

const MaterialBottomTabNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Bookmarks: BookmarksScreen,
    Auditions: AuditionsScreen,
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
  },
  {
    shifting: true,
    initialRouteName: 'Auditions',
    barStyle: {  backgroundColor: 'black' },
  }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={<ActivityIndicator />} persistor={persistor}>
          <MaterialBottomTabNavigator />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: mapStateToProps update the components props after redux change. if you want to update state inside each component after it you need to use 'componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)'

Comment: why do you connect the `AuditionItem ` component to the store if you are passing `auditons ` from the parent ?

Comment: Actually, the AuditionItem(s) are part of multiple AuditionLists. Each AuditionList is filtered according to a different criteria (eg. Film, TV, All, etc). So a AuditionItem can belong to multiple AuditionList (say Film and TV). Now when the user presses on the bookmark icon, I want the icon to change on ALL audition items with that id belonging to multiple lists.That's why I want to pass auditions to the global store.

Comment: can you share the code inside App.js ?

Comment: Sure, I'l add the code. But the issue was a typo suggested in the answer comments below.

Comment: Added code for App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This doesn't create an instance of the class**, it just exports the class/object.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AuditionItem)
```

[Export reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

You get the instance when you call the constructor of the class, but that's after importing it. So basically, all the time you use the imported AuditionItem (i.e: < AuditionItem />) React internally is creating a new instance of the class.

I guess the problem is either on `AuditionItem` itself, or the props you're passing to.

> **Additional information about `mapStateToProps`
>   from the [official](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments) Redux documentation**
>
> [mapStateToProps(state, [ownProps]): stateProps] (Function): If this argument is specified, the new component will subscribe to Redux store updates. This means that any time the store is updated, mapStateToProps will be called. The results of mapStateToProps must be a plain object, which will be merged into the component’s props. If you don't want to subscribe to store updates, pass null or undefined in place of mapStateToProps.

Comment: I'll post the code to AudtionItem in my question. But are you saying that mapStateToProps should automatically be called multiple times for each state change?

Comment: mapStateToProps only listens to Redux changes, not the component state. You want to listen to the component state changes?

Comment: No. I want to listen to the Redux global state changes. Added code.

Comment: Why are you calling Redux's store like `store.getState()` when you're using connect's HOC? Anyways, Flatlist is a special PureComponent, which means that, it will only update children when the object inside `data` prop changes. I guess that two things and the fact that you have a typo over AuditionItem's mapStateToProps (auditons) may be causing the problem

Comment: Have one thing in mind, only if the props passed to the component or if the component's state changes, it will re-render, and re-render children. `connect`'s HOC helps you with that, because it passes props down to your component, if you use `store.getState()` it will only get the data if the component re-renders for one of the reasons above, if that doesn't happen, it won't trigger the change and so `store.getState()` won't get called.

Comment: The problem was in the typo. Thanks v.much for pointing that out. It's rendering correclty now. Thanks again.

Comment: I'll refactor the code according to your suggestion also. Thanks v.much for those also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174068/discussion-between-st4rl00rd-and-nparabz).